# Languages with [yø̯]

Tags: phonology, phonemes, vowels

The Finnish language has the (presumably) extremely rare diphthong [yø̯], which is a front rounded vowel opening and falling diphthong. I know that this diphthong also exists in some other Finnic languages, as well as the Finnish Kalo language, which despite being Indo-European has obviously been influenced by Finnish.

Are there any languages that are neither Finnic nor in contact with Finnic languages that have this diphthong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHOIBLE](https://phoible.org/) is a useful resource for questions like this about the presence of certain segments in phonemic inventories.

First of all, it's important to note that Finnish [yø] is not typically considered a single morpheme, but is rather considered a sequence of two separate vowel phonemes (likewise the long vowels of Finnish are typically analysed as a sequence of two of the same vowel).

That said PHOIBLE does list five inventories (for four distinct languages) with segments possibly corresponding to Finnish [yø̯].

A vowel [yø](https://phoible.org/parameters/2ECCDDB16D4285722A8B5603DAE11005#3/53.56/76.57) and/or [y̯ø](https://phoible.org/parameters/BE552A1E3D6E7D7BFC98641451FAFC8A#6/43.500/45.500) is listed for:

- Wymysorys (Ritchie 2012)
- Standard Sakha (Tolkov 2011)
- Ploskost Chechen (Nichols 1996; Магомедов 1974)

A vowel [yø̞](https://phoible.org/parameters/3845A2B2A7F88E1F1935BB13EDD165CC#3/63.49/82.42) is listed for:

- Yakut Sakha (Bohtlingk 1964; Krueger 1962; Ubrjatova 1966)
- North Karelian (Зайков 1999)

A vowel [yœ](https://phoible.org/parameters/C929BC8425ED764D5D4986B1A3C66032#6/71.108/94.294) and/or [yœː](https://phoible.org/parameters/470017D2898A158A2C5261FFE1CAE871#0/0/0) is listed for:

- Dolgan (Ubrjatova 1985)
- Elfdalian (Sapir 2006)

Karelian is obviously closely related to Finnish, so not of much interest to us. None of the other languages have had significant contact with Finnic however (although Sakha, Dolgan, and Elfdalian have all had contact with other Uralic populations).

Note, other sources may transcribe some of these segments differently (e.g. I believe the yø segment listed here for Wymysorys is the ʏ̯øœ̯ listed in Andrason & Król 2016) and due to the limits of PHOIBLE, languages that are analysed in a similar way to Finnish, with this seen as a sequence of two distinct vowel morphemes rather than a single diphthongal segment are not listed.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the coastal Min topolects (of Fujian Province, in southeastern China) have various front rounded diphthongs. The largest of these is Min Dong, the prestige dialect of which is Fuzhounese. Both the opening diphthong /yo/ and closing /øy~ɔy/ exist. Although conventionally transcribed /yo/, it is far more common to hear this being fronted all the way through the diphthong, phonetically [yø]: see recordings for [橋(桥)](https://www.ydict.net/w/CgQxMDE5) (BUC: *giò*) "bridge", [藥/药](https://www.ydict.net/w/KhJDZ1VLQS1pUnJ4QUxHQmtnQnc) (BUC: *iŏh*) "medicine", and [香](https://www.ydict.net/w/CgQxNDlE) (BUC: *hiŏng*) "fragrant".